# Mysql for Excel - BUG - displaying wrong parameters

Tags: mysql, excel

When I click on **"New Connection"** instead of seeing the normal parameters

```
(Connection name, method, Hostname, Username etc)
```

I see only two fields **" MySQL Username:"** and **"H.A Groups Filter:"**

If I move the tab to **SSL** or **Advance** the window doesn't change and I still see the same two fields I described above. I also can't see any connections in the sidebar.

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: btw, I already tried reinstalling the plugin, the connector and even excel. I'm using Mysql Connector Net 8.0.11, Mysql for Excel 1.3.7 and Mysql Workbench 6.3 CE

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, and it was working fine until I did an office 365 update.  Tried reinstalling office and mysql for excel, still the same problem.  Did you manage to sort this out?  Thx